# Rails: N+1 queries being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, eager-loading

I have a Conversation model that `has_many` messages. In my query, I have

`@active_conversations = Conversation.includes(:messages)..........`

This solved my N+1 queries for the most part. Here is my problem:

index.html.erb

```
<% @active_conversations.each do |conversation| %>

<div class="<%= 'unread' if conversation.has_unread_messages?(current_user) %>">

<span><%= conversation.messages.first.body.truncate(50) %></span>

</div> 

<%end%>
```

Conversation.rb

```
  def has_unread_messages?(user)
    !self.messages.unread.where(:receiver_id => user.id).empty?
  end
```

Message.rb

```
  def self.unread
    where("read_at IS NULL")
  end
```

There is no n+1 issue for `conversation.message.body`

The issue is with - `if conversation.has_unread_messages?(current_user)` because for every conversation it is running that query to check if the messages in that conversation have not been read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have included the `:messages` on your query, you have all messages loaded, so you don't really need another query to check if it is unread and if all the conversation messages are unread. You can create methods that check these states:

```
def has_unread_messages?(user)
  unread = self.messages.collect {|m| m.read_at.nil? && m.receiver_id == user.id}
  !unread.empty?
end
```

All of your messages inside the `@conversation.messages` are preloaded.

**Updated**

Here is updated solution:

```
def has_unread_messages?(user) 
  messages.any? { |message| message.read_at.nil? && message.receiver_id == user.id } 
end
```

Comment: def has_unread_messages?(user)
      messages.find { |message| message.read_at? && message.receiver_id == user.id }.any?
    end

Comment: +1 I was about to propose adding another attribute via `Conversion.select('conversations.*, (SELECT ...) AS unread_messages')` but that would not be as elegant.

Comment: Try the "bullet" gem.

Comment: @pratski Well, maybe you will have to adapt the method to your needs, but you got the idea. If you don't want to generate n+1 queries this is one of the ways you could do it.

Comment: I believe in my example it is the opposite. Just flag the last line `!unread.empty?`.

Comment: `find` returns the found *element*, not a `Enumerable`. Just replace `any?` it with `present?` or ditch it altogether.